# Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS error

Tags: sql-server

i am trying to create sql server procedure with if statement. 
i am new to the ms sql server however i tried with the following statements but it gave me the below error **Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Procedure te, Line 9
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.**

**here is the code i wrote**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test as 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
if (select COUNT(load),load,contractor_id from [test].[dbo].[cont]
  group by load,contractor_id
  having load = (select MIN(load)from [test].[dbo].[cont])
   ) > 1 
  begin 
  SELECT top 1 COUNT(*),load ,contractor_id,name
  FROM [test].[dbo].[cont]
  group by load,contractor_id,name
  having load = (select MIN(load)from [test].[dbo].[cont])
  ORDER BY NEWID()
   end 
  ELSE
   BEGIN
  SELECT top 1 COUNT(*),load ,contractor_id,name
  FROM [test].[dbo].[cont]
  group by load,contractor_id,name
  having load = (select MIN(load)from [test].[dbo].[cont])
   END
END

GO
```

can anyone help please

Comment: Why do you not just run the `ORDER BY NEWID()` variant of the inner query and get rid of all of the conditional code - unless there's some other difference that I've not spotted, you seem to be doing a lot of work to avoid applying an `ORDER BY` clause if it so happens that the query only returns one row anyway, which seems like a pointless amount of work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says you cannot have multiple column selected when you use IF condition. In your first IF condition you are selecting multiple columns, however if conditions requires to have a query that can lead to one value. Other option is you have to use IF EXISTS, that can check count >1 as below

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(load),load,contractor_id 
  FROM [test].[dbo].[cont]
  GROUP BY load,contractor_id
  HAVING load = (SELECT MIN(load)
                 FROM [test].[dbo].[cont])
  AND COUNT(load) >1)
```

Another thing what I noticed is you are excecuting the query which calculates the min of load multiple times. You can avoid that by storing it in a variable and use it further.

I have modified the procedure as below. Check if this works or not.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test as 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @count INT
DECLARE @minload INT
SELECT @minload = MIN(load)from [test].[dbo].[cont]
SELECT @count = COUNT(load)  from [test].[dbo].[cont]
  GROUP BY load,contractor_id
  HAVING load = @minload

IF (@count) > 1 
  BEGIN 
      SELECT top 1 COUNT(*),load ,contractor_id,name
      FROM [test].[dbo].[cont]
      WHERE load = @minload
      GROUP BY load,contractor_id,name
      ORDER BY NEWID()
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
      SELECT top 1 COUNT(*),load ,contractor_id,name
      FROM [test].[dbo].[cont]
      GROUP BY load,contractor_id,name
      HAVING load = @minload
  END
END
```

**UPDATE**

Based on your comments, I suppose you can get the result with one simple query as below.

```
;WITH minLoad(load)
AS
(
    SELECT MIN(load) 
    FROM [test].[dbo].[cont]

)
SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(*),c.load ,c.contractor_id,c.name
FROM [test].[dbo].[cont] c, minLoad
WHERE c.load = minLoad.load
ORDER BY NEWID();
```

Comment: thank you dear for your support. actually i am trying to create a procedure which will give me an output with the following logic : i have a list of contractors with load of each one and i want the procedure to check : if there is a contractor with less load then new job will be assigned to him else if there is a group of contractors with the same load then the system will select one of them randomly. e.g there are 3 contractors in my list two of them are having the same load which is 10 jobs per each and last contractor has 15 jobs so the system will select one of the two. hope you got it

Comment: thank you dear it is really helped . Appreciating your cooperation :)

Comment: how to call this procedure in asp page and display the output in a text filed ?

Comment: You dont need a procedure. You can just use it like a simeple query. You can set the above query as the command text for the sqlcommand object

Comment: thank you for being with me. what i want to do is that there is a button the client will press on the button then the result will be displayed in textbox so can it be like this ?

Comment: In summary on click of the button, you need to write code which opens connection, create command, for the command text give the above query, open connection, call excecute scalar function(because you only need count(*)), get the return value and display it in the textbox.